# Unflagging (by rule) doesnt show rightaway

Tags: ajax, javascript, rules, flags

I have 3 flags in my custom content type "Movie" 
Seen , Unseen , Want to see...

these 3 flags are mutually exclusive , that is if a user has "seen" a movie he cant "unseen" the movie..

To make the flags mutually exclusive I have added rules , so whenever one of the flags are flagged, the other 2 are unflagged.

Now my problem is, when i flag a movie with say "seen" , the other 2 flags "unseen" and "want to see" are unflagged internally, but that unflagging effect is not visible on that page right away. When i refresh the page , then i can see those changes.

How can , i see the changes right away ??

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using flag's javascript toggle to set these flags, and if that's correct, you could hook into flag's `flagGlobalAfterLinkUpdate` event and refresh the portion of the page where your flags are set.  More details are here:  http://drupal.org/node/336122.  If you don't want to do this, you could always set the flag link to a normal link, which would refresh the page for you in of itself.